# Is it possible to marry your wife's sister?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, non-mahram

Am I correct you are not allowed to marry more than 1 sister at the same time so how Islamically would it be possible if at all? In what situation?

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your question brother, to simplify, you asked is marrying two wives who are sisters haram (impermissible) or not in islam. My answer is that in islam it is not permissible to marry two wives who are sisters in islam mainly because it would create jealousy and problems, etc. Neverthless, the islamic ruling is that it is haram and it is not allowed to marry two wives who are sisters or any more the proof for this is the verse of the Quran where Allah almighty says:

> "*Forbidden to you [in marriage] are[:]... two sisters in wedlock at the same time except for what has already passed*" [Al-nisaa' 4:23]

from this verse we understand that it is forbidden to marry two sisters or have two sisters in marriage at the same time, even if they share only one parent or they are foster-sisters. End quote.